# How to mock Django queryset which was got from related_name?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, django-queryset

I want to unittest this function, which is service-function inside my Django app:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from account.models import Profile
from lesson.models import Lesson, Question
from repeat.models import RepetitionSession


class QuestionService:
    @staticmethod
    def get_next_question_by_rep_session(rep_session: RepetitionSession) -> Question:
        today_date = date.today()
        questions_filter = rep_session.questions.filter(next_repeat_at=today_date)
        sorted_questions_filter = questions_filter.order_by('edited_at')
        next_question = sorted_questions_filter.first()
        return next_question
```

It was like this, but I've separated it for 3 lines:

```
next_question = rep_session.questions.filter(next_repeat_at=today_date).order_by('edited_at').first()
```

Here is my unittest:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from random import randint
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
from django.test import SimpleTestCase
from lesson.services import QuestionService


class QuestionServicesTest(SimpleTestCase):
    FILE_PATH = 'lesson.services.question_service'

    def test_get_next_question_by_rep_session(self):
        test_query = MagicMock()
        test_question = MagicMock()
        test_rep_session = MagicMock()

        test_rep_session.questions = test_query
        test_query.filter().return_value = test_query
        test_query.order_by().return_value = test_query
        test_query.first().return_value = test_question

        result = QuestionService.get_next_question_by_rep_session(test_rep_session)

        test_query.filter().assert_called_once_with(next_repeat_at=date.today())
```

I'm getting this fail
https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Dzl.png

AssertionError: Expected 'mock' to be called once. Called 0 times.
Calls: [call.order_by('edited_at'), call.order_by().first()].

So if I want to test filter() I'm usually do this:

```
    @patch(f'{FILE_PATH}.Model_name.objects.filter') 
    def test_example_func(self, patch_filter):

    test_attr = MagickMock() 
    test_query = MagickMock()
    patch_filter.return_value = test_query
    
    result = example_func(test_attr)
    
    patch_filter.assert_called_once_with(test_attr)
```

Please, help me find what I've missed.

Comment: Is there any reason why are you mocking DB queries? Usually, it's good practice to actually create DB objects in test DB during tests and create/remove different objects in your DB while testing.

Comment: @SergeyPugach 
Yes, the reason is django.test.SimpleTestCase disallows database queries by default.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.databases

Also as far as I know unittesting is about testing one layer of logic. I perform complex  testing in integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my mistake. Lets see changes:

```
    def test_get_next_question_by_rep_session(self):
        test_query = MagicMock()
        expected_question = MagicMock()
        fail_question = MagicMock()
        test_rep_session = MagicMock()

        test_rep_session.questions = test_query
        test_query.filter.return_value = test_query  # Mistake was here
        test_query.order_by.return_value = test_query  # Mistake was here
        test_query.first.return_value = expected_question  # Mistake was here

        result = QuestionService.get_next_question_by_rep_session(test_rep_session)

        test_query.filter.assert_called_once_with(next_repeat_at=date.today())  # Mistake was here
        test_query.order_by.assert_called_once_with('edited_at')
        test_query.first.assert_called_once()
        self.assertEqual(result, expected_question)
        self.assertNotEqual(result, fail_question)
```

So when we mock objects it works like that:

```
x.return_value = 420
# When we will call x we will get 420
>>> x()
>>> 420

def x() -> y:
     ...

x().return_value = 665
# However when we will call result of the x() we will get 665
>>> y
>>> 665
```

If I did mistake somewhere please let me know.